# What is "nullsub_XXX" in vtable in IDA

Tags: ida, c++, static-analysis, vtables

When I looking in a vtable structure in IDA pro, I know that `___cxa_pure_virtual` means that the function is virtual.

But what does `nullsub_XXX` mean in a vtable structure?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Welcome to the Reverse engineering stack exchange Q&A site! Although you only asked about `nullsub_`, you described `___cxa_pure_virtual` slightly incorrectly so I'll describe it as well*

#### nullsub_X

IDA makes a minimal effort of providing meaningful, yet general, names for functions according to their implementation by adding a prefix or name for certain *types* of functions.

One such case is `nullsub`, which is a name automatically given (during the analysis phase) to all *empty* functions. Meaning functions that simply return without doing **anything**.

Additionally, since names are unique in IDA, when an in-use name is set to a function IDA will postfix it with an underscore and then an auto-incremented number (starting with 1).

If you're wondering why such functions should exist in the first place, [this](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2420/what-are-nullsub-functions-in-ida/2422#2422) post answers that question quite diligently.

#### ___cxa_pure_virtual

This is a function implemented by [`libstdc++`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/) (and a similar function is implemented by other C++ standard libraries) as a place-holder to **pure** virtual functions in virtual function tables.

Although pure virtual functions have no implementation the compiler cannot eliminate the risk of pure virtual functions being called at run-time, and so a stub such as `___cxa_pure_virtual` is used as a place-holder for all pure virtual functions, so that if it ever happens that a pure virtual function would be called at runtime, there an explicit handling (termination of the program with a somewhat meaningful crash, often).